# I'm trying to pass an ArrayList object from the main class to a sub class. What should i do?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

Alright so here is my variable:

```
private ArrayList<Socket> socketArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

And here is the method in the main class used to pull this variable from this class to another one.

```
public ArrayList<Socket> getArrayList() {
     return socketArray;
}
```

However, my main class runs its code in a thread and every time another class invokes the ArrayList method to get the ArrayList, it creates a new thread in addition to the current one(s).

What can I do to make this not happen or should I rewrite the program entirely because I have written it in a way that isn't practical?

I can post the rest of the code if need be.

I know this is a lot of code and I appreciate any and all help!

Edit:

```
package chatprogram;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


public class ChatProgram implements Runnable
{
    ClientHandler ch;
    Socket socket;
    ServerSocket ss;
    boolean checkRun = false;
    Thread clientThread = null;
    private ArrayList<Socket> socketArray = new ArrayList<>();
    public ChatProgram()
    {
            addThread();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        { 
            ss = new ServerSocket(0);
            System.out.println(ss);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        } 

        while(!checkRun)
        {
            try
            {
                socket = ss.accept();
                ch = new ClientHandler(socket);
                socketArray.add(socket);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                System.out.println(ioe);
            }

        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Socket> getArrayList() {
         return socketArray;
    }

    public void addThread()
    {
        if (clientThread==null)
        {
            clientThread = new Thread(this);
            clientThread.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatProgram start = new ChatProgram();
    }

}
```

And the class that calls to the main class to get the ArrayList:

```
package chatprogram;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClientBroadcast implements Runnable {
    String inputVar;
    Thread thread; 
    Socket socket;
    boolean checkRun = false;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    public ClientBroadcast(String input,Socket s,DataOutputStream dataout)
    {

        inputVar = input; 
        socket = s; 
        dos = dataout;
        start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        ArrayList<Socket> socketArray = new ChatProgram().getArrayList();
        try
        {
            while(true)
            {
                for(int i = 1;i< socketArray.size() + 1;i++)
                {
                DataOutputStream dataout = new DataOutputStream(socketArray.get(i).getOutputStream());
                dataout.writeUTF("Eureka!" + socketArray.get(i));
                System.out.println(i + "here");
            }
            int i = 0;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioerror)
    {
        System.out.println(ioerror);
    }

    } 

    public void start()
    {
        if(thread == null)
        {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        if(thread != null)
        {
            thread.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could your please post the rest of your code?

Comment: This doesn't look particularly thread safe to me. I would suggest that you read up on thread safety before writing threaded code.

Comment: I dont understand the meaning of `every time another class invokes the ArrayList method to get the ArrayList, it creates a new thread in addition to the current one(s).` I need to see more codes.

Comment: I posted the code to the main class and the other class I was referring to. There is a third class called ClientHandler. Let me know if you need this as well. I'm sorry, I've only been playing around with java off and on for around 6 months now. I'm new to all of this!

Comment: Calling getArrayList() doesn't create a new thread.

Comment: I think your issue is that you are creating a new ChatProgram when all you want to do is call getArrayList() on an existing instance of ChatProgram

Comment: Where do you create your instance of ClientBroadcast? You should pass your instance of ChatProgram into the constructor of ClientBroadcast. And then use that ChatProgram instance when you want to call  getArrayList()

Comment: @bhspencer That's a brilliant idea. I'll try that out!

Comment: @bhspencer you are totally right! with ArrayList<Socket> socketArray = new ChatProgram().getArrayList(); I'm creating a new chatProgram! I totally overlooked that.